# How to delete ' ' around the numbers in my list but not the strings

Tags: python, string, multidimensional-array, indexing, int

So I have a multidimensional list with strings and ints in it. But i need to organize the list in increasing order by the numbers. The problem is that my numbers have ' ' around them for example `'181'`. I don't want to remove the ' ' from the strings I just want to remove it from the ints.

My List looks like this:

```
[['"Detective Pikachu"', '104', 'PG'], ['"The Secret Life of Pets 2"', '86', 'PG'], ['"Deadpool 2"', '119', 'R'], ['"Godzilla: King of the Monsters"', '132', 'PG-13
'], ['"Avengers: Endgame"', '181', 'PG-13'], ['"The Lion King(1994)"', '88', 'G']]
```

I just want this:

```
[['"Detective Pikachu"', 104, 'PG'], ['"The Secret Life of Pets 2"', 86, 'PG'], ['"Deadpool 2"', 119, 'R'], ['"Godzilla: King of the Monsters"', 132, 'PG-13
'], ['"Avengers: Endgame"', 181, 'PG-13'], ['"The Lion King(1994)"', 88, 'G']]
```

Comment: Is it always the second element in the inner list and are the inner lists always three items long?

Comment: Yes the int is always the second item in the inner list and each inner list is 3 items long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lists = [
    ['"Detective Pikachu"', '104', 'PG'],
    ['"The Secret Life of Pets 2"', '86', 'PG'],
    ['"Deadpool 2"', '119', 'R'],
    ['"Godzilla: King of the Monsters"', '132', 'PG-13'],
    ['"Avengers: Endgame"', '181', 'PG-13'],
    ['"The Lion King(1994)"', '88', 'G']
]

new_lists = [[int(item) if item.isdigit() else item for item in current_list] for current_list in lists]
```

Answer (score 1):

The ints have quotes around them because they aren't actually ints, they're strings -- so to restate the problem, you want to convert all of the strings to ints where it's possible to do so, and leave the rest of the strings alone.

I don't think there's a built in "maybe convert to int" function in Python, so I'd start by making one:

```
def maybe_convert_to_int(value: str) -> Union[int, str]
    try:
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

and then just map that function over each movie list:

```
[movie.map(maybe_convert_to_int) for movie in movie_list]
```